# can't find element by xpath using Java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I try this xpath but I don't know how to continue from here ?
How to click on the element "8th day" ?
I am using selenium webdriver with java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class='dates']/div[@class='pointer']...);
```

I don't know how to continue, when I add " /div['8'] " i get an error

the html of the page is:

```
    <div id="monthlist" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div style="left: -1px; position: absolute;">
<div class="month" style="left: 0px;">
<div class="title">יוני  2016    </div>
<div class="weekdays_top"></div>
<div class="body">
<div class="weekdays">
<div class="dates">
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">1</div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">2</div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">3</div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">4</div>
<div class="pointer today" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">5</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">6</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">7</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">8</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">9</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">10</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">11</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">12</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">13</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">14</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">15</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">16</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">17</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">18</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">19</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">20</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">21</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">22</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">23</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">24</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">25</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">26</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">27</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">28</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">29</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">30</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
<div style="left: 163px; position: absolute;">
<div class="month" style="left: 164px;">
<div class="title">יולי  2016    </div>
<div class="weekdays_top"></div>
<div class="body">
<div class="weekdays">
<div class="dates">
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
<div class="invalid" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);"></div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">1</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">2</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">3</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">4</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">5</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">6</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">7</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">8</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">9</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">10</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">11</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">12</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">13</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">14</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">15</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">16</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">17</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">18</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">19</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">20</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">21</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">22</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">23</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">24</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">25</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">26</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">27</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">28</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">29</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">30</div>
<div class="pointer" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);">31</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tweaking the answer @alecxe gave above...It looks from the example that the 8th day does not always appear in the same place in the document, therefore try:

```
WebElement desiredElement = driver.findElements(
    By.xpath("//div[@class='dates']/div[@class='pointer' and text()='8']")
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think you can use `findElement` instead of `findElements`.

Answer (score 0):

If the position of the desired element is fixed, would be to use `findElements()` and get the desired element *by index* from the list:

```
WebElement desiredElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dates']/div[@class='pointer']").get(7);
```

We use `7` since indexing starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//div[@class='dates']/div[@class='pointer' and contains(text(),'8')]);
```